# Up-to-date example of kubernetes audit log policy

Tags: kubernetes, audit-logging

Kubernetes has a kind of up2date audit policy file in [configure-helper.sh](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/ec434662bdb56579f8f4b65a7c8a38a698b08bfb/cluster/gce/gci/configure-helper.sh#L743).
Unfortunately, it does not include recent functionality. For example, it lacks exclusions for the CronJob controller (user= `system:serviceaccount:kube-system:cronjob-controller`).

Can anybody share a less verbose policy file?

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you want to get rid of in logs? Stackoverflow is not the best place to exchange files. May be you could rephrase your question to help other people learn from the answers, how to write audit policy, for example.